# Magento admin side customization

Tags: php, magento

I am doing a magento customization  admin panel site , client need is  to add new  usertype in admin panel and they can visible some functionality of admin panel. Client's magento version is 1.4.x , here l am  attaching an image i need to remove the tab `product view optimization` from  catalog's section.the latest version magento has not these feature . so i need to know which file i need to update to remove this left tab. Please help.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The tab `Product View Optimization` is used by `Google API - Google Website Optimizer`. If you're not using Google's Website Optimizer at all, you can deactivate the output of that module completely:

- Go to *System* => *Configuration* => *Advanced* and disable the output for `Mage_GoogleOptimizer`.
- Go to *System* => *Configuration* => *Google API* and deactivate Google Website Optimizer.

Hope that helps!